# Converter implemented but still having error "Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter' "

Tags: jsf, converters

I have a big problem with Converter class. I am using **h:selectOneMenu** to select a "category" for my Enetity "Product". When i submit form, then i get following error :

•Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.

I can not find what is wrong with my implementation. 
Also i am searching how to do that working with Seam-Faces... 
Any ideas? 
Thanx.

I am using JSF **Mojarra 2.1.2 (FCS 20110613), GlassFish v 3.1, PrimeFaces 2.x, PrettyFaces 3.x and JPA 2.0.**

MY JSF page:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="selectCategory"
                                 value="#{productController.category}">                 
                    <f:selectItems value="#{categoryController.listCategory()}"  var="category" itemLabel="#{category.name}" itemValue="#{category}"/> 
                    <f:converter converterId="categoryConverter" />    
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

MY Converter class :

```
 @FacesConverter(forClass=Category.class, value="categoryConverter")
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter {
    private CategoryController ctrl;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        ctrl = (CategoryController) context.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(
                context.getELContext(), null, "categoryController");        

        Category category = ctrl.findById(Integer.valueOf(value));
        return category; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        return "" + ((Category) value).getCategoryid();
    }
}
```

some part of my ProductController Class :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productController")
@RequestScoped
ProductController class

        public ProductController{
    private Category category;
    //getters :: setters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but I had tried it with system.outs. Values are send correctly by submit and returned right category object for the given value (#ID). but still having the same error.

Anyway.... I have found the problem. Converter works fine as expected.

Only thing that causes the error was that the field product."image" . I had no converter for image field. When i removed this line from JSF form, it is submitted without errors.

Type of image property is a byte and so it also needs to be converted in the JSF such as other fields that are not a String.

just a beginner error i know:)

StringToByteConverter:
[here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224633/convert-inputtext-to-byte-in-jsf)